# Pass Nested Deserialized JSON from Controller to View

Tags: c#, .net, json, model-view-controller, httpclient

After using **HttpClient** class to convert my JSON to a string and deserialize it with

```
var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(response);
```

How do I pass the data that I receive in the Controller from the call using the Model below to the View?

```
        public class RuleType
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public bool Inactive { get; set; }
        }

        public class RuleCategory
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public bool Inactive { get; set; }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public object EndDateTime { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public bool Inactive { get; set; }
            public int RuleAction { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
            public RuleType RuleType { get; set; }
            public RuleCategory RuleCategory { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is one object from the call

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Test Description",
        "EndDateTime": null,
        "Id": 1,
        "Inactive": false,
        "RuleAction": -2,
        "StartDateTime": "2017-01-06T14:58:58Z",
        "RuleType": {
            "Id": 6,
            "Description": "Test Description",
            "Inactive": false
        },
        "RuleCategory": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Description": "Description",
            "Inactive": false
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: That JSON string contains an array of `RootObject` instances, not an `Employee` object. The `Employee` doesn't have *any* properties so there's nothing to (de)serialize

Comment: Okay I see thank you. So I should just remove the encompassing Employee class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but if you have an object you want to return to the view from the controller, you simply:

```
return View(viewModel); // in your case viewModel = 'data'
```

Comment: Thanks Johnathan. I've returned that but in my `foreach (var item in Model)` loop I'm now getting the message System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: So the viewModel, or part of it, does not have what is expected. Put a breakpoint in the controller before you return and inspect the viewModel. Your serialization is probably not working as expected. If so, your question is not correct, as it wouldn't be an issue with passing nested data to a view

Answer (score 0):

As others have said here already, you should be deserializing the JSON into a RootObject instead of an Employee like so:

```
var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(response);
```

You can then pass the model into the view using just:

```
return View(data)
```

You should also consider renaming RootObject into something more useful (such as employee?) as RootObject is not a very useful or descriptive name.